Can a plugin/card created using plugin framework be force enabled for all users by default
Say we are creating a PFM plugin/card using "Banno plugin framework". Once it is enabled for a given user, the user is required to visit the "Organize Dashboard" and add the PFM plugin that we enabled for the user.
Instead can we just make this PFM plugin available by default on the user's dashboard. User can then remove the PFM if they don't see it useful. Do we have such feature in Banno Admin portal, where we can make a plugin be inserted into user's dashboard by default ?

The institution can add a plugin card to the default dashboard for users. For users that have not customized their own dashboard, the plugin will show up by default. For users that have customized their own dashboard, the user will need to add the card to their dashboard using the "Organize dashboard" feature.

Thanks Jaime, that answers my question
